# How to tell if/when Postgres triggers are executing

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I'm working in a legacy codebase/database. The code previously depended on triggers but at one point stopped using them - the logic was moved into the main (Nodejs) codebase and the `CREATE TRIGGER` statements were removed. Nonetheless, the triggers still exist in the DB. I can see them searching the `pg_trigger` table:
[image]

As far as I can tell they're still enabled which is weird because to my knowledge they shouldn't be doing anything. If they're not being used I'd like to remove them. My questions:

1. Is there way to tell the last time a trigger executed?
2. Are there any other ways I can figure out if these triggers are even doing anything anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that, unless you modify the triggers to record the execution somewhere.

Perhaps `session_replication_role` is set to `replica`. Then normal triggers (`tgenabled = 'O'`) don't fire.